$\gamma (t)=(t^3-3t,t^4-2t^2) \text{:}t \in \mathbb{R}$. Set $\gamma (\mathbb{R})$ cuts plane into many areas, one is bounded - calculate its measure.
I found such problem with solution.

Problem:
We have $\gamma (t) = (t^3 - 3t, t^4 - 2t^2) \text{ for: } t \in \mathbb{R}$. Set $\gamma (\mathbb{R})$ cuts the plane into several areas, one of which is bounded. Calculate its measure.

Solution:
Solving the equation $\gamma (t_1) = \gamma (t_2)$ we can find the solution $t_1 = \pm \sqrt{3}$ and $t_2 = -t_1$. In view of this, the fragment corresponding to $t \in [-3, 3]$ bounds the area we are looking for. We can calculate its measure using Green's formula:
$$\lambda_(D) = \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} \left( t^3 - 3t \right) \left( t^4 - 2t^2 \right)' \ dt = \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} 4 \left( t^3 - 3t \right) \left( t^3 - t \right)' \ dt = - \frac{96 \sqrt{3}}{35}$$
The result came out negative. It means we forgot the orientation and need to change it to the opposite one. Therefore:
$$\lambda_(D) = \frac{96 \sqrt{3}}{35}$$

There are two things that I don't understand here. First is the solution of $\gamma (t_1) = \gamma (t_2)$. Calculating that, as I understand it, from the first equation get:
$$t_1^3 - 3t_1 = t_2^3 - 3t_2$$
$$t_1^3 - t_2^3 = 3t_1 - 3t_2$$
$$(t_1 - t_2)(t_1^2 + t_1 t_2 + t_2^2) = 3(t_1 - t_2)$$
$$t_1^2 + t_1 t_2 + t_2^2 = 3$$
From the other equation I get:
$$t_1^4 - 2t_1^2 = t_2^4 - 2t_2^2$$
$$t_1^4 - t_2^4 = 2t_1^2 - 2t_2^2$$
$$(t_1^2 - t_2^2)(t_1^2 + t_2^2) = 2(t_1^2 - t_2^2)$$
$$t_1^2 + t_2^2 = 2$$
We can now use that result in the former equation:
$$t_1^2 + t_1 t_2 + t_2^2 = 3 \implies t_1 t_2 = 1 \implies t_1 = \frac{1}{t_2}$$
And from that:
$$t_1^2 + t_2^2 = 2 \implies \left( \frac{1}{t_2} \right)^2 + t_2^2 = 2 \implies \frac{1}{t_2^2} + t_2^2 = 2 \implies 1 + t_2^4 = 2t_2^2 \implies t_2^4 - 2t_2^2 + 1 = 0 \implies (t_2^2 - 1)^2 = 0$$
Finally I get: $t_2^2 = 1 \implies t_2 = \pm 1 =  t_1$.
Therefore, I probably don't understand how to solve the equation $\gamma (t_1) = \gamma (t_2)$ properly.

Second thing is the use of Green's formula. I thought that Green's formula looks like that (as described in the wikipedia article):
$$ \int_C \left( L dx + M dy \right) = \int \int_D \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} \ dA$$
But that formula wouldn't match the one used in the solution that is provided to the problem. Therefore I think there might be some simplification of the formula that is not described and I don't understand what is that and why it can be applied here.

Singularities. The implicitzation of your rational quartic curve, $x^4+6x^2y-y^3-2x^2+6y^2-9y=0,$ has three singular points ideal(y-3,x), ideal(4*x+3*y-5,(y+1)^2), ideal(4*x-3*y+5,(y+1)^2), a node at $(0,3)$ or $t=\pm\sqrt3$, and cusps at $(\pm 2,-1)$ for $t=\pm 1.$


The solution that you found is not relevant to the problem, since $t_1=t_2$ implies $\gamma(t_1)=\gamma(t_2)$ trivially. In order to obtain a nontrivial solution, notice that the equation
$(t_1^2 - t_2^2)(t_1^2 + t_2^2) = 2(t_1^2 - t_2^2)$ implies $t_1^2+t_2^2=2$ or $t_1=t_2$ or $t_1=-t_2$. The first equation, as you showed, leads to the solution $t_1=t_2=\pm 1$, which is a particular case of the trivial solution $t_1=t_2$. On the other hand, the third equation, when combined with the equation $t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2=3$, yields the solution $(t_1,t_2)=(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3})$, which corresponds to the point $\gamma(-\sqrt{3})=\gamma(\sqrt{3})=(0,3)$ (see the figure below, obtained with WolframAlpha).



If we choose $M=\frac{x}{2}$ and $L=-\frac{y}{2}$ in the Green's formula
$$
\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)dA=\oint_C(Ldx+Mdy), \tag{1}
$$
we obtain
$$
\iint_DdA=\oint_C\left(-\frac{y}{2}dx+\frac{x}{2}dy\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}(-y(t)x'(t)+x(t)y'(t))\,dt. \tag{2}
$$
Integrating by parts the first term on the RHS of $(2)$, we get
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}y(t)x'(t)\,dt=\underbrace{-\left.\frac{1}{2}y(t)x(t)\right|_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}}_{=\,0}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}x(t)y'(t)\,dt. \tag{3}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we finally obtain
$$
A(D)=\iint_DdA=\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}x(t)y'(t)\,dt=\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}(t^3-3t)(t^4-2t^2)'\,dt. \tag{4}
$$

